# How to express $\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu}$ as a linear combination of {1, $\gamma^5, \gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{u} \gamma^5, \sigma^{\mu \nu}$}?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

**
EDIT: I think I have completely missed the mark on asking my question. Here is another try.

I do not understand what a linear combination means in this situation. My naive desire is to have an expression with all the terms from the basis. Yet this does not work dimensionally.

What should I be thinking in this situation when I read linear combination?
**

I have been given the following question:

> Express $\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu}$ as a linear combination of {1, $\gamma^5, \gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{u} \gamma^5, \sigma^{\mu \nu}$}

Originally I wanted to come up with some answer like,
$$
\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu}  = a\mathbf{1}+ b\gamma^5 + c\gamma^{\mu} + d \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^5 +e \sigma^{\mu \nu}
$$
However, this is obviously wrong on so many levels (its painful to look at. I apologize for any bleeding of the eyes that has occurred).

My question now is how am I supposed to interpret "linear combination"? So far my route in coming up with an answer is the following:

$$
\sigma^{\mu \nu} = \frac{i}{2}(\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu} -\gamma^{\nu} \gamma^{\mu}) \Rightarrow \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu} = \frac{2}{i} \sigma^{\mu\nu} + \gamma^{\nu} \gamma^{\mu}
$$
Which is looking like a semi ok start. I have taken this in several different directions and all leaving me feeling unsure of my goal. Which brings us full circle to how should I be interpreting the question?

Comment: I am unsure with what the goal of your advice is? Are you suggesting that taking the trace will help me figure something out that is new? Or are you suggesting I take the trace to see why the original thing I was thinking was wrong?

Comment: You're always allowed to use the metric $\eta^{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: To have the proper index structure, one would need to add invariant tensors. The only invariant tensors in 4d Minkowski space are the metric and the Levi-Civita, and we can disregard the latter. Thus the Ansatz should be $\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu = a g^{\mu\nu} + b g^{\mu\nu} \gamma^5 + e\sigma^{\mu\nu}$. One can realize that we must have $b = 0$ because $\gamma^5$ is pseudo-scalar.

Comment: @RobinEkman I am interested in your comment. What line of thinking should I have in order to get to where you got with your Ansatz? This is getting closer to figuring out what I am missing in my understanding.

Comment: It's the principle that in a tensor equation, all terms must have the same transformation properties, and therefore index structure. So the coefficients in the linear combination must be *tensors* of the appropriate kind, contracted in appropriate ways.

Comment: So in a sense  I could start with my original naive idea... then by tensor structure I could immediately say that a=b=c=d= 0 ? This would leave me with the correct tensor structure on either side, however it does not get me the two $g^{\mu\nu}$ terms you have.

Comment: @RobinEkman I think I got it... I am gonna edit your answer and see if you follow.

Comment: The proper conclusion is that $\mathbb 1$ must appear multiplied with some tensor with two indices, and e.g. $\gamma^\mu$ must appear multiplied by a 1-tensor or contracted with a 3-tensor. Because there is no invariantly defined 1-tensor or 3-tensor, $\gamma^\mu$ can't appear in the equation. There is however (only) one invariant 2-tensor, the metric, so $\mathbb 1$ can appear if and only if it's multiplied by $g^{\mu\nu}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu - \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu = \frac{2}{i} \sigma^{\mu\nu} $$
but $\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu = -\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + 2g^{\mu\nu} $ so
$$2\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + 2g^{\mu\nu} = \frac 2 i \sigma^{\mu\nu}.$$

Relevant comment from Robin

$\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu$ is a matrix-valued two-tensor. The 16 listed matrices are a complete set, so each component of $\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu$ is a linear combination of those 16 matrices. The coefficients can depend on $\mu$ and $\nu$. However, because the components form the component of a tensor, and subsets of the basis matrices also form the components of tensors, the coefficients appearing in the linear combinations must depend on $\mu,\nu$ only as being the components of tensors. But the only tensor the coefficients can form is the metric.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47258/discussion-on-answer-by-robin-ekman-how-to-express-gamma-mu-gamma-nu-a).

Answer (score 0):

I would apply the expression for anti-commutators of gamma-matrices to your last line of formulas.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150365)

Comment: @gonenc: I respectfully disagree. I actually gave the same advice as that of the later (accepted) answer by Robin Ekman. Furthermore, full answers to homework questions are discouraged here.